# How to configrue Jenkins with Star team repository?

Tags: build, repository, hudson, jenkins

In my project we are using star team repositories to store source code. I need to build from the STAR TEAM repository using Jenkin Tool. How can I set up to configure star team. So that if enter my star team id and password, all projects have to list out with my login access. If you are having any idea, please let me know.